# Add code to Workbook_Open()

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a piece of code that will put the following code into a new excel workbook that has been created. The generated code should be

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
End Sub
```

At the moment I am using the following code, and the new workbook is the active workbook.

```
Public Sub AddNewModule()

Dim proj As VBIDE.VBProject
Dim comp As VBIDE.VBComponent

Set proj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
Set comp = proj.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ct_StdModule)
comp.Name = "MyNewModule"

Set codeMod = comp.CodeModule

With codeMod
  lineNum = .CountOfLines + 1
  .InsertLines lineNum, "Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  lineNum = lineNum + 1
  .InsertLines lineNum, "ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll"
  lineNum = lineNum + 1
  .InsertLines lineNum, "End Sub"
End With

End Sub
```

Does anyone know where I am going wrong or anything that can help me?

Comment: Did you try adding " at the end of "Private Sub Workbook_Open()? (;

Comment: So much easier to use a template that already has that code in. Or set whatever it is you need refreshing to refresh on workbok open without code.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying (Short And Sweet)?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    With ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(ActiveWorkbook.CodeName).CodeModule
        .InsertLines Line:=.CreateEventProc("Open", "Workbook") + 1, _
        String:=vbCrLf & "ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll"
    End With
End Sub
```